# FeatureCollection (Error) Image.reduceRegions: Group input must come after weighted inputs

Tags: google-earth-engine, band, feature-collection, reducers

I was trying to find the area of each block by category in the band. There is one band and it has 18 categories. The feature collection is a collection of blocks described uniquely by code_2011.

```
var image1 = ee.Image ("image_name");
var andhra = ee.FeatureCollection("Feature_name");

var image2 = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(image1);

var result = image2.reduceRegions({
    collection: andhra.select(['2011_code']),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 0,
    groupName: 'code',
  }),
    scale: 50
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('sum', null)
  ).flatten();
```

Comment: Welcome to the GIS StackExchange! Please include a reproducible example in your code. As it is, there is no actual data included in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just from the order of the bands in the `image`. EE wants absolutely that the *grouping variable* comes after the *variable to be reduced*. So you will never be able to use  `groupField: 0` (meaning grouping variable is first).

To see this, you can just invert the order of the bands in the documentation on  [grouped reductions](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_grouping):

- `nlDiff.select(["Land_Cover_Type_1", "stable_lights"])` with `groupField: 0` will NOT work
- `nlDiff.select(["stable_lights", "Land_Cover_Type_1"])` with `groupField: 1` WILL work. This is the case implicit in the documentation.

Code:

```
// Load a region representing the United States
var region = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'United States'));

// Load MODIS land cover categories in 2001.
var landcover = ee.Image('MODIS/051/MCD12Q1/2001_01_01')
  // Select the IGBP classification band.
  .select('Land_Cover_Type_1');

// Load nightlights image inputs.
var nl2001 = ee.Image('NOAA/DMSP-OLS/NIGHTTIME_LIGHTS/F152001')
  .select('stable_lights');
var nl2012 = ee.Image('NOAA/DMSP-OLS/NIGHTTIME_LIGHTS/F182012')
  .select('stable_lights');

// Compute the nightlights decadal difference, add land cover codes.
var nlDiff = nl2012.subtract(nl2001).addBands(landcover);

// Grouped a mean reducer: change of nightlights by land cover category.
var means = nlDiff.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'code',
  }),
  geometry: region.geometry(),
  scale: 1000,
  maxPixels: 1e8
});

// Print the resultant Dictionary.
print(means);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a band to the existing band and call that band instead of the original one.

```
var image1 = ee.Image ("image_name");
var andhra = ee.FeatureCollection("Feature_name");

var image2 = ee.Image.addBands(image1);

var result = image2.reduceRegions({
    collection: andhra.select(['2011_code']),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1,
    groupName: 'code',
  }),
    scale: 50
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('sum', null)
  ).flatten();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. A reproducible example would be great though, it seems your code would not run!?